# How to exit Nashorn jjs command line tool?

Tags: java, nashorn, jjs

If I start up the Nashorn CLI via `jjs`, I can't cleanly exit it without using <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>.

I tried:

- `exit`
- `quit`
- `System.exit()`

But none worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/nashorn/shell.html):

> **`quit()`**
>   **`exit()`**
>
> These functions are synonymous, causing the current
>   script process to exit to the system.
>
> You can pass an integer value as
>   the argument that represents the exit code to be returned to the
>   system. By default, without an argument, the exit code is set to 0,
>   meaning that the process terminated correctly.

Enter either `exit()` or `quit()` to exit the Nashorn shell.

Comment: Also, java.lang.System.exit(0) calls the java call directly.

Answer (score 1):

Simply typing "exit" or "quit" won't work! That will just print toString on those functions (something like "function() { [native code] }"). You need to call those functions like "exit()" or "exit(2)". Also, you need to invoke java.lang.System.exit(int) with fully qualified package name "java.lang" (unlike java where java.lang is always imported!)